# Is It possible to use Lightning app exchange components in custom lightning app?

Tags: salesforce, components, lightning

*i installed a lightning component from app exchange ,now i  want to use that component in my custom lightning app*

**is it possible??**

```
<aura:app>
//code for adding components

</aura:app>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with components:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>     
    {!v.body}    
</aura:component>
```

And in the controller ("mvc:CalendarComponent" as example, put here your component):

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    $A.createComponent(
        "mvc:CalendarComponent",
        {

        },
        function(newCmp){
            if (component.isValid()) {                    
                component.set("v.body", newCmp);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Can't we use <mvc:CalendarComponent /> directly?